# Can I create an app folder in OneDrive. I do not want app to have access to all of OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365-apps

For either OneDrive personal or business is it possible to have a single folder in OneDrive my app has access to without having access to all of OneDrive.  Currently I am requesting permission from user to access all of Onedrive and setting this up manually, but users typically do not like giving access to all of OneDrive if its not a specific OneDrive app.

I feel like I have read about AppFolder permissions but I cannot find supporting documentation or examples of it being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permission you're looking for is `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` and it's documented in the [file permissions category](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#files-permissions).

Description: `Have full access to the application's folder (preview)` and `(Preview) Allows the app to read, create, update, and delete files in the application's folder.`

Once your application has an access token with this permission, your app folder is located at `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/special/approot/`.

Uploading, downloading and listing the files is just like any other folder from this point. For example, listing the items in this folder is done with GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/special/approot/children`.

Uploading a file:

PUT `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/special/approot:/foo.txt:/content`

Comment: Note: this permission only works with Personal accounts and not Business ones.